# What is the meter of the poem "Snow" by Louis MacNeice?

Tags: poetry, meter, louis-macneice

I'm struggling to find the meter in which the poem ["Snow"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/91395/snow-582b58513ffae) is written. I know that Shakespeare's poetry was written in iambic pentameter.

So far, I've read that the poem "Snow" has a rough meter, and since that wasn't enough, I tried finding it myself, but I'm really struggling.

Comment: It's not free verse?

Comment: The [dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/free_verse) defines *free verse* as "poetry that does not rhyme or have a regular rhythm." If we take that definition, this is clearly not free verse, since it rhymes. It also has more of a rhythm than most modern free verse.

Comment: On the other hand, Amy Lowell's poem [*Patterns*](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/42987/patterns) is often classified as free verse. And if *Patterns* is free verse, then *Snow* also is.

Answer (score 2):

Even free verse can include an occasional rhyme. The key is its metrical irregularity and avoidance of being defined as a fixed form.

So what makes this poem interesting is that is *appears* to have regularity, because of the repeated 4-line verse paragraphs, which look like a regular stanzaic form. But the unpredictable meter contradicts this appearance, giving us two opposites at the same time: regularity and irregularity.

The poem's form is mirroring its content: the world is "collateral and incompatible" and "Incorrigibly plural." It doesn't fit a single category: winter and summer, "spiteful and gay," all at the same time. Opposites, just like the poetic form.

I don't know MacNiece's work, but this is a lovely and intriguing piece, and this is how I make sense of it.

Comment: Do you mean *free verse* and not *blank verse*? Blank verse is unrhymed **iambic pentameter**, which this is certainly not.

Comment: Thank you, @Peter Shor. Correction made.